How does the iterm2 Python API determine which tab a script is running in?
I have a set of window tabs I use regularly, and when I start up iTerm2, I restore this using "Window->Restore Window Arrangement".
In .bashrc, I'd like to use the Iterm Python API to set the bash history filename to match the tab's title.
To do this, I wrote a Python script using the iterm python API to get the tab title:
  import iterm2
  async def main(connection):
    app = await iterm2.async_get_app(connection)
    window = app.current_window
    tab = app.current_terminal_window.current_tab
    title = (await tab.async_get_variable("titleOverride"))

  iterm2.run_until_complete(main)

However, this doesn't work as "current_tab" is the frontmost tab, which happens to be the last tab opened - not the tab the current .bashrc is running in.
For example, in the screenshot, the "current_tab" is "Apache", so all the instances of the script report it as the "current_tab", whereas what I need is 'Src', 'Bld', etc.
I've consulted the documentation and can't find a solution.
How can I do this?


Soooo, with a bit of help I was able to write a Python script which accomplished what I wanted, though it's the "opposite" way of what I'd intended: It creates the tabs and names them, rather than interpreting a tab.
You just start up iTerm2 and run this in a shell. A new window will be opened and your tabs set up as you like them.
Here's the script in case anyone else would like some inspiration:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import iterm2
import colorsys

def hsv_to_rgb(h, s, v):
    r, g, b = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(h/360, s, v)
    return int(r*255), int(g*255), int(b*255)

async def main(connection):
    app = await iterm2.async_get_app(connection)

    # Create a new window
    window = await iterm2.Window.async_create(connection)

    # Get the initial tab (the extra one we want to close later)
    initial_tab = window.current_tab

    # Generate 8 colors
    colors = [
        iterm2.Color(*hsv_to_rgb(0, 1, 1)),    # Red
        iterm2.Color(*hsv_to_rgb(42, 1, 1)),   # Orange
        ...more colors here...
        iterm2.Color(*hsv_to_rgb(297, 1, 1)),  # Violet
    ]

    # Define tabs with their names and corresponding directories
    tabs = [
        {"name": "Src", "dir": "...directory for Src Tab...", "cmd": "...initial command for Src Tab...", "color": colors[0]},
        {"name": "Bld", "dir": "...directory for Bld Tab...", "cmd": "...initial command for Bld Tab...", "color": colors[1]},
        ... More Tabs Here ...
        {"name": "Sandbox", "dir": "...directory for Sandbox Tab...", "color": colors[7]}
    ]

    for tab_info in tabs:
        print("Handling Tab " + tab_info['name'])
        # Create a new tab
        tab = await window.async_create_tab()
        # Set the tab title
        await tab.async_set_title(tab_info["name"])
        # Get the session in the current tab
        session = tab.current_session
        # Set up a unique bash history file for this tab
        history_file = f"~/.bash_history_{tab_info['name'].lower().replace(' ', '_')}"
        # Send commands to set up the unique history file and change directory
        await session.async_send_text(f"export HISTFILE={history_file}\n")
        await session.async_send_text(f"history -r {history_file}\n")
        await session.async_send_text(f"cd {tab_info['dir']}\n")
        # Run initial command if specified
        if "cmd" in tab_info:
            await session.async_send_text(f"{tab_info['cmd']}\n")
        if "color" in tab_info:
            change = iterm2.LocalWriteOnlyProfile()
            change.set_tab_color(tab_info['color'])
            change.set_use_tab_color(True)
            await session.async_set_profile_properties(change)
        # Optional: Clear the screen for a clean start
        # await session.async_send_text("clear\n")

    # Close the initial tab
    if initial_tab:
        await initial_tab.async_close()

# Run the script with retry=True
iterm2.run_until_complete(main, retry=True)

